# python regex: will inclusion/deletion of ( ) or groups from regex creates difference in pattern matching?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match phone number stored in some string

> > > str = """ Vijendra contact number is 8861005000
> > >       Srinu contact number is 8861005001
> > >       pankaj contact number is +91-8861005002
> > >       prasad contact number is +92-8861005003"""

for above string i have created regex like this    a=re.compile(r'(+\d+-)?(\d+)')

and it is able to fetch the contact numbers properly

> > > a.findall(str)

[('', '8861005000'), ('', '8861005001'), ('+91-', '8861005002'), ('+92-', '8861005003')]

Now i have only removed ( ) from my regex and now regex looks like this     a=re.compile(r'(+\d+-)?\d+')

this time when i am trying to fetch contact number stored in my string i am getting a string with only area codes as its values

['', '', '+91-', '+92-']

why new regex is not able to fetch the contact number ? and fetching only area codes?

I am using python 2.7.12

Comment: Turn all capturing groups into non-capturing. `r'(?:\+\d+-)?\d+'`

Comment: Hi Wiktor, can you please explain your comment/answer more

Comment: Read the Python docs about `re.findall`, it is all described there. Capturing groups are returned if they are present in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at non capturing groups in regex.
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups

If you use these you can add your groups but they will not be returned as results.